# Pytest and Django settings runtime changes

Tags: python, django, pytest, pytest-django

I have a receiver that needs to know whether `DEBUG` set to `True` in my `settings.py`.

```
from django.conf import settings
...
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_fake_firebaseUID(sender, instance, created=False, **kwargs):
    # Fake firebaseUID if in DEBUG mode for development purposes
    if created and settings.DEBUG:
        try:
            instance.userprofile
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance, firebaseUID=str(uuid.uuid4()))
```

The problem is that when I create a user using `manage.py shell` everything works as expected. However, if I run my tests via `py.test`, the value of `settings.DEBUG` changes to `False`. If I check it in `conftest.py` in `pytest_configure`, `DEBUG` is set to `True`. It changes somewhere later and I have no idea where.

What can cause this? I am sure that I do not change it anywhere in my code.

Edit.

conftest.py

```
import uuid

import pytest
import tempfile
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


@pytest.fixture(scope='session', autouse=True)
def set_media_temp_folder():
    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as temp_dir:
        settings.MEDIA_ROOT = temp_dir
        yield None


def create_normal_user() -> User:
    username = str(uuid.uuid4())[:30]
    user = User.objects.create(username=username)
    user.set_password('12345')
    user.save()
    return user


@pytest.fixture
def normal_user() -> User:
    return create_normal_user()


@pytest.fixture
def normal_user2() -> User:
    return create_normal_user()
```

myapp/tests/conftest.py

```
# encoding: utf-8
import os

import pytest
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import SimpleUploadedFile

from userprofile.models import ProfilePicture


@pytest.fixture
def test_image() -> bytes:
    DIR_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    with open(os.path.join(DIR_PATH, 'test_image.jpg'), 'rb') as f:
        yield f


@pytest.fixture
def profile_picture(test_image, normal_user) -> ProfilePicture:
    picture = SimpleUploadedFile(name='test_image.jpg',
                                 content=test_image.read(),
                                 content_type='image/png')
    profile_picture = ProfilePicture.objects.get(userprofile__user=normal_user)
    profile_picture.picture = picture
    profile_picture.save()
    return profile_picture
```

pytest.ini

```
[pytest]
addopts = --reuse-db
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings
```

Comment: It's hard to say why your tests are showing `DEBUG` as `False` if you don't provide the code for your tests. It would also be helpful to see your `conftest.py`.

Comment: Also, are you using the import `from django.conf import settings`? If you import your settings module directly, this can cause strange issues.

Answer (score 14):

Apparently pytest-django explicitly sets DEBUG to False ([source code link](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-django/blob/master/pytest_django/plugin.py#L445)).

Diving through the git history of pytest-django a bit, this was done to match [Django's default behavior](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/overview/#other-test-conditions) ([pytest commit link](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-django/commit/2821e4178fa09732cbdaaf4ac369ada0e0b8f558)).

From the Django docs:

> Regardless of the value of the DEBUG setting in your configuration file, all Django tests run with DEBUG=False. This is to ensure that
>   the observed output of your code matches what will be seen in a
>   production setting.

As a workaround you can use [pytest-django's `settings` fixture](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/helpers.html#settings) to override so DEBUG=True if you need it to be. For example,

```
def test_my_thing(settings):
    settings.DEBUG = True
    # ... do your test ...
```

Answer (score 7):

For anyone who is having similar problem. I found the reason. I downloaded source files of pytest-django and found out that it sets DEBUG to False in `pytest-django/pytest_django/plugin.py:338`. I do not know why tho.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I did some digging based on it and I put up another answer with some explanation. But IMO you have it exactly right. Hopefully the added context will help someone else out.

Answer (score 4):

Add the following line in the pytest.ini file:

```
django_debug_mode = True
```

Comment: This worked for me while using pytest-django